# Landmine bar question!

Tags: squats, barbell, barbell-rows

Can you do landline reps with a 5-ft bar? I’m 5’7” female, 45, Med-build. I know most landmine users use a 7’Olympic bar, but I’m just starting out, and I’m not sure if I should buy a 5’, 6’, or 7’. I also don’t want to unnecessarily take up space with a really long bar if I don’t have to. Eventually, I hope to work my way to the 7’ standard bar, but I’m not sure right now if it makes a big difference for me to go with a 5’ or 6’. Thoughts??

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can do most things with a 5' landmine bar that you could do with a 7' landmine bar.

The main difference between the two lengths is a 5' landmine bar arch will be smaller than the 7'. This could be a problem for very tall people or people with long reaches when they want to do something like [a landmine press](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x071zV-Bo2E). They would have to sit or kneel down to get the full effect. Any exercise off the floor shouldn't be affected significantly.